# What laws and regulations were violated by John Oliver's critique of Chinese President Xi Jinping?

Tags: international-relations, china, social-media, censorship, xi-jinping

[*The Associated Press* reports](https://www.apnews.com/87cac8f64e334f97a6f1aa4f15b3c43a) that John Oliver hosted a segment on his show *Last Week Tonight* in which he criticized Chinese President Xi Jinping. In particular, he said that he looked like Winnie the Pooh and criticized policy under his rule of sending Muslims to political indoctrination camps. This resulted in the Chinese government blocking access to him on social media.

> Attempts to send posts Friday with either the terms "John Oliver" or "Last Week Tonight" on the Sina Weibo microblog were met with failure messages saying "the content contains information that violates relevant laws and regulations."

What specifically were the laws and regulations that John Oliver's content violated?

Comment: It looks a lot like a law.se question, but perhaps it is a implementation question about the Great Firewall.

Comment: Please clarify as to whether this is in regards to *Chinese* laws, international laws,   US laws, or perhaps some combination of those.

Comment: @agc That's my question: what were the laws that were violated? Were they Chinese, international, US or some combination?

Comment: Also, is it clear that this seemingly legal error message isn't the accidental result of some configuration error on the part of the GFW admins?  Perhaps they were just trying to keep tabs on public opinion, but mixed up some keyword logging filter with a blocking filter.  A poorly designed interface would make such problems more likely.

Answer (score 11):

Well, there is not really any law authorizing the GFW (***G***reat **F**ire**w**all) at all. Why do you expect that this has violated a law?

If I must pick one law that it violated, then I'd say it violated Article 12 of the [Cyber Security Law of the PRC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China_Internet_Security_Law), which forbids using the Internet to *"injure the State's security, honor and interests"*, or to *"infringe on other individuals' reputation"*. Which is extremely broad, as intended.

There might indeed be a regulation that says *"please take this down immediately"*, but usually those regulations are passed by the pertinent gov't agencies directly to the Internet corporations, without being publicized to the general public. The only way the general public learns about them is by hearsay. Not a typical "regulation" in the Western sense.

In case anyone is interested, I have not found an English translation of  the law. But if you read Chinese it's [here](http://www.npc.gov.cn/npc/xinwen/2016-11/07/content_2001605.htm).

Comment: "Why do you expect that this has violated a law?" Because that's exactly what the error message says and what news sites are reporting. I think I'd like something more than speculation to answer this.

Comment: @Thunderforge Well, it would be naïve to interpret this message literally, given the censorship and lack of rule of law in China. There might indeed be a regulation that ordains Sina Weibo to take the contents down, but usually those regulations are passed by the pertinent gov't agencies directly to the Internet corporations, without being publicized to the general public. Not a typicla "regulation" in the Western sense.

Comment: A link to the actual text of the law would be useful.

Comment: @agc I have not found an English translation of the law, and the Chinese version is easily found online. I was translating from the Chinese text.

Comment: Ok, why isn't the Cyber Security Law of the PRC a reasonable answer to the original question?

Comment: @puppetsock Because it is way too vague. What in the world counts as "infringing on the state's interests"? Anything can be counted as that if the authorities wish so. Moreover, no article in the law empowers authorities to take down "illegal" content, so technically this law does not authorize the authorities to do so (but this is China, and of course they do it anyway).

Comment: @Xuq01  So, you're saying that a law in China is vague and so can't apply? Actually, it's very clear. It forbids the act. What's vague is, who decides? Well, who does decide on the honor and interests of the state? That would be the state. So, this law clearly authorizes the state to stop anything on the net it decides to.  For example, for a while a couple months ago, the letter "P" was banned because of some kind of meme about Xi and Winnie the Pooh.

Comment: @puppetsock Sure it can apply. But I am not sure this kind of answer is what the OP wants. It would be akin to answering a question about a very specific civil rights issue in the US with the Equal Protection Clause. Sure the Equal Protection Clause is the root of everything, but there are numerous nuances in the application of the law; the same for this case. All censorship in China can be explained by this law on a high level, but that does not mean all of it is totally legal. As I mentioned above, no article in the law authorizes any authority to take down any content that's deemed illegal.

Comment: @puppetsock (cont'd) Similarly, no mechanism is provided to determine what constitutes an illegal message. In other words, Article 12 of the said law is not enforceable by itself. So I would argue that the takedown is not based on law: even if the government agencies are, in fact, empowered to determine the legality of Internet content, they are not authorized to take it down. Again, it's China, so they will do it anyway, but having some vague words on paper doesn't mean it legalizes "everything".

Comment: @xuq01 Without a trial you can never know for sure which law might potentially have been violated. The error message is not very specific and might even lie, so this answer is probably the best one can come up with.

Comment: Yes, but I guess the more appropriate answer is that in China, "by law" = someone in the government told me to do so.